# Phonegap image gallery and large pictures

Tags: image, html, cordova, mobile

I am working on a phonegap HTML5 mobile application to display all the photos on my phone.  I need to show the pictures as thumbnails, let the user select many of them and then upload to the cloud server.

I found many great examples on how to do display the photos as thumbnails and got a simple version working.  But, since the photos are all 3mb, I can only show a few before my app uses a lot of memory (and crashes).  Does anyone have a recommendation on the right way to do create thumbnails?

Right now I just create an img tag in a loop (of the files) and use a CSS to set the width/height to 60 px.  Here is the snippet:

```
$('#gallery').append('<div class="' + uiBlockClass +'"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="'+ entry.fullPath+'" title="'+ entry.name+ '" /></div></div>');
```

and the CSS:
    .thumbnail{
        padding:5px;
        height:60px;
        width:60px;
    }

I did see some stuff on using a canvas and tried a simple exmaple, but that also seemed to run out of memory.  My mobile app is in HTML5 and uses phonegap.  The entry is a fileEntry from the HTML5/phonegap code.

Comment: Why not create the images at two sizes rather than resizing them to create the thumbnails?

Comment: These are photos on a users phone.  It's not images from the cloud where I have control like that.  Is there a way to create thumbnails on a phone?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to load the images into phonegap one at a time so you don't run out of memory, copy them to the canvas, then unload them, something like this:

```
var thumbnailWidth = 100; // Thumbnail width in pixels
var gap=10; // gap between thumbnails
var sourceImagePaths = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg"]; // paths to source images   
var y=0; // vertical offset on canvas
var i=0; // image index
var image = new Image();
var context = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

function loadImage(){
  image.onload = onImageLoad;
  image.src = sourceImagePaths[i];
}

function onImageLoad(){
  var height = Math.round((thumbnailWidth/image.width)*image.height);           
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, y, thumbnailWidth, height);      
  y+= height + gap;
  image.src = null;
  i++;
  if(i<sourceImagePaths.length){
    loadImage();
  }
}     
loadImage(); // load images
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpa99c/M2yYp/

Comment: So nulling out the image src (after the drawImage) will free up the memory for img?  I actually did try using a canvas (previously) but still had the memory problem.  I'll trying nulling out the img.src and see if that works.  Thanks for your reply!  Once I confirm I'll mark this as a answer/resolved.